# smart keyboard in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO I have need to develop online keyboard using jQuery or anything else that can help me achieve following.

1. When I type any letter , it can check against bunch of words and keep only those Keys enable which are possible.

For example. In my word collection I have word "Hello". When I type "H" on the keyboard...it should only keep "e" "l" "o" keys enabled and everything else should be disabled.

Is there a Name for such keyboards ? Any Examples would be appreciated. Currently I am planing to do this using jQuery and AJAX. I can keep my word collection on server and then do a look up on every kep press.

Ved

Comment: As a former UX guy at a major software company... I am unfamiliar with any names for such a keyboard.  However, it sounds like you've got the right baseline architecture in your head.  Functionally, this isn't different from an Ajax Autocomplete... all you're doing is setting a bunch of UI styling with each update.  Heck, I'd just have the web service spit you back an array of allowed characters, from the current buffer as a parameter.

Comment: The Honda Navigation System that comes with their cars has this functionality - essentially, when you type a letter, it predicts/knows what letters are available to follow. So it blanks out/dims the letters that are not available, such as if you type "f" to start a word, z, x, t, etc... are blanked out.

Comment: The basic logic for this doesn't seem hard. A starting point would be to hit your server every time a key is pressed. On the server you'd have to look up all words beginning with what the user has typed so far. Then, you'd have to add the letters following candidate words to a collection and send it back down.

Comment: I think this might be considered a Predictive Keyboard (Google it for more examples). A video example of one type would be: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQme9koF5Gs

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer - I don't think an exact one would be possible here.

Perhaps you could use the custom meta set keyboard from Trufa's suggestion and combine that with one of the jQuery autocomplete plugins to update your word list and change the keys that are available.

If you wanted to use the full keyboard I'm sure there would be a way using jQuery selectors to activate and deactivate certain keys.

Comment: humm using jQuery selectors to activate and deactivate...good idea